# WPF TreeView data Grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm attempting to use TreeView control that needs to be bound with an object containing few string properties and a single list of object.

```
// Represent a device on network
public class Device
{
    // Name to identify the device
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Type of the device i.e. {USB_2.0, USB_3.0, Parallel etc}
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    // Time when device detected
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    // Total active time of the device on network
    public TimeSpan ActiveTime { get; set; }

}

// Represent a network having multiple devices
public class Network
{
    // Identifier of the network or network name
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    // Name of the network administrator
    public string Admin { get; set; }
    // List of devices connected
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

trying to achieve given structure in the tree view:
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43UTp.png)

So given code, how could I apply grouping for the children at each level in the hierarchy?

Tried few approaches using the CollectionViewSouce but I guess not doing it correctly.

Comment: Unclear question. Figure too doesn't tell anything.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Sorry if I'm unclear about what I' trying to say. I want to bind a list of "Network" class to the tree view control grouped using the type of device type. Like we have multiple networks each network have a number of devices grouped using the device type value.

Comment: Can you explain using example of `Drive/Directory/File/Subdirectory`.

Comment: Let's supposed we have a Hard drive containing 3 logical partitions.
Ist partition contains a single folder named CriticalFiles and a single file name DriveInfo.
CriticalFiles folder contains a number files that need to be grouped using their file type or file extension (.i.e. - Avi, Gif, txt, mov etc)

At root, we have Drive containing number of folder as children and each folder contains number of files as children which are grouped using the extension property.